# Do the number of website views influence Domain Authority?

Tags: seo, domains, page-views

If you have more views on your, does this affect your Domain Authority (the 0-100 score developed by Moz)?

By views I mean a 'session' as defined by google analytics "A certain period of time a user is engaged with your website'

Comment: Website views as in clicks from Google Search, page-views tracked by Google Analytics, or something else?

Comment: While it doesn't specifically answer this question, Moz has a document about domain authority: [Moz: What is Domain Authority?](https://moz.com/learn/seo/domain-authority)

Comment: @dan I have edited the question to be more clear

Comment: Short answer? No. No-one external to your website can measure traffic to your website or within it. MOZ is one of those sites that drives me nuts. While there is a fair amount of good stuff out there, much of it is out of date, wrong, misleading, or speculation. The MOZ metrics are okay, but do not put too much stock in them. If you are chasing MOZ metrics, you are chasing your tail. It is a marketing device to get you dependent upon them for your success and pay money for. Your are supposed to fret over every change and number. Please don't do that. Save your sanity. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

"Domain Authority" is an arbitrary metric that is generated in different ways by different services. So Moz, ahrefs, SEMRush, etc. can all have a different formula for generating their own take Domain Authority. To that end, pageviews *could*, theoretically, affect a Domain Authority formula if that 3rd part company feels it's relevant.

Now, any arbitrary metric created by one of these third party tools is supposed to mirror an *actual* internal metric used by search engines. Let's call this internal metric "Real Domain Authority," the secret amalgamation of factors that help determine a website's rank in Google's search results.

Is Real Domain Authority influenced by visits? **Almost certainly not.** Why? Because you can buy or generate visits, real or fake, infinitely. It would destroy the equal playing field that search results are supposed to be, and it wouldn't necessarily indicate quality.

There *has* been talk of CTR (click-through rate) from search results affecting search results, though. There's no way of ever knowing for **sure**, only speculatively, because Google's search engine algorithm is not public.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Here is the link to the official source on Moz about [what DA is, etc.](https://moz.com/learn/seo/domain-authority)

If you want to influence DA I'd focus on quality links rather than hits on the website.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. Because there are several program that can generate robots visits leading to fake traffic. Google analytics is also base upon   the time the user spent , the number of page and the event click.